'LogisticRegressionTrainingSummary' object has no attribute 'fMeasureByThreshold'
I'm new to Pyspark and Databricks and trying to create a Logistic regression model (going through the Spark_DS&ML_exercise provided by Databrticks itself). After fitting the model to my training data. I'm trying to get the f-measure from the summary by threshold.
I ran the following code:
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

# Create initial LogisticRegression model
lr = LogisticRegression(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", maxIter=10)

# set threshold for the probability above which to predict a 1
lr.setThreshold(train_positive_rate)
# lr.setThreshold(0.5) # could use this if knew you had balanced data

# Train model with Training Data
lrModel = lr.fit(train)

# get training summary used for eval metrics and other params
lrTrainingSummary = lrModel.summary

# Find the best model threshold if you would like to use that instead of the empirical positve rate
fMeasure = lrTrainingSummary.fMeasureByThreshold

But I'm getting this AttributeError:
AttributeError: 'LogisticRegressionTrainingSummary' object has no attribute 'fMeasureByThreshold'

It seems the fMeasureByThreshold doesn't exist anymore. Is it the case?

So, I've found the answer. The method that I'm looking for resides in BinaryLogisticRegressionTrainingSummary and not LogisticRegressionTrainingSummary. The former is the summary of a binomial logistic regression model (mine is multinomial). For the latter, the only way to get f-measure is by label using fMeasureByLabel.
